Weird behavior when navigating in a double nested navigator
It seems the state of my application is wrongfully handling nested navigators. My page's style doesn't apply properly until a fast refresh is triggered.
My project is currently having the following structure:
- StackNavigator
-- (loggedIn?) MainTabNavigator (1)
-- (!loggedIn)
--- StartScreen
--- LoginScreen
--- SignupScreen

(1) MainTabNavigator
-- HomeTabScreen
-- StoreScreen
-- StockNavigator (2)

(2) StockNavigator 
-- StockScreen
-- StockDetailScreen

So as you can see, I have a StackNavigator, nested in a TabNavigator, nested in another StackNavigator.
Here is my StockNavigator definition:
<StockStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={'StockScreen'}
    presentation="card"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      cardOverlayEnabled: false,
      cardShadowEnabled: false
    }}
  >
    <StockStack.Screen name="StockScreen" component={StockScreen} />
    <StockStack.Screen name="StockDetailScreen" component={StockDetailScreen} />
  </StockStack.Navigator>

Everything goes fine until I'm on my StockScreen and wants to navigate to my StockDetailScreen
Here is how I'm navigating from one to another
navigation = useNavigation();
...
navigation.navigate('StockNavigator', { screen: 'StockDetailScreen' });

And here is a sample of my StockDetailScreen page:
const StockDetailScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <IconButton icon={require('../../assets/icons/close.png')} style={styles.closeWindowButton} size={25} onPress={onBackAction} />
        </View>
    );
};

styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#171A1F',
        padding: 20
    },
    closeWindowButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        zIndex: 99999,
        tintColor: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
});

As you can see, my main view on this screen is supposed to have a dark backgroundColor, but when I navigate, I get these weird styles where the background of the view is white, the button to close the window, which is supposed to be placed at the top right is on the top left corner.
And if I do any modification, such as adding a comment, triggering a fast refresh, it then renders correctly and places all my components properly.
It only does this with these 2 screens specifically.
I tried going to the simplest, even by moving StockScreen and StockDetailScreen to the MainTabNavigator as Tabs, but it always renders the same.

I should also specify that if I install the debug APK without going through the react-native CLI, or if I clear the cache, the output is the same.
